# changing size of a block device in c linux

Tags: c, linux, file, block, device

I have written a function that should change the size of any block device
lsblk command gives this output

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 457.9G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

my function is->

```
int _some_func(
            int path,
                int size)
{
        struct  stat stat_buf;

        /*check if file is valid*/ 
        if(!((fcntl(path, F_GETFL) != -1) || (errno != EBADF)))
        {
                perror("invalid file descriptor\n");
                return -1;
        }

        /*get file properties in stat_buf*/
        if( -1 == fstat(path, &stat_buf))
        {
                perror("error in stat\n");
                return -1;
        }

        /*return error -1 if file is not block device*/
        if((stat_buf.st_mode & S_IFMT) != S_IFBLK)
        {
                perror("not a block device\n");
                return -1;
        }

        return(ftruncate(path,size) );

}

int main()
{
        long int curr_size = 0;
        struct  stat stat_buf;
        int fd = open("/dev/sda1",O_RDWR,0777);
        if(fd < 0)  perror("error\n");

        /*get file properties in stat_buf*/
        if( -1 == fstat(fd, &stat_buf))
        {
                perror("error in stat\n");
                return -1;
        }

        curr_size = stat_buf.st_size;
        printf("current size =%ld\n",curr_size);
        if(_ss_size(fd,curr_size+50) == 0)
        {
                /*get file properties in stat_buf*/
                if( -1 == fstat(fd, &stat_buf))
                {
                        perror("error in stat\n");
                        return -1;
                }

                curr_size = stat_buf.st_size;
                printf("changed size =%ld\n",curr_size);

        }
        else
        {
                perror("error in _ss_size\n");
        }



}
```

output is->
current size =0
error in _ss_size

### : Invalid argument

1>why the current size of "/dev/sda1" is showing as 0,but in lsblk size is = 457.9G
2>why error in _ss_size
: Invalid argument is coming(this is the return value of)
ftruncate command.

if ftruncate does not work, then which sys call will work?

Comment: There is no single system call that allows you to shrink a volume (i.e. a block device), at least not in a non-destructive way.

Comment: what is the non-destructive way and what are its impacts?

Comment: The best and most non-destructive way involves no programming, but using `gparted`.  If you want to know how it's done, *use the source, Luke* - But don't expect to find a trivial program.